# what's the pythonic way to count the occurrence of an element in a list?

Tags: python

this is what I did. is there a better way in python?

```
for k in a_list:   
  if kvMap.has_key(k):
    kvMap[k]=kvMap[k]+1   
  else:
    kvMap[k]=1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
kvmap= defaultdict(int)
for k in a_list:
    kvmap[k] += 1
```

Comment: The first time I encountered defaultdict was in Peter Norvig's spelling corrector article. In a couple of lines, he pulls in a file of words and converts it to a dictionary of key=word value=count. Way cool.


http://www.norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Answer (score 9):

Single element:

```
a_list.count(k)
```

All elements:

```
counts = dict((k, a_list.count(k)) for k in set(a_list))
```

Comment: Is that not fairly inefficient?  You're converting the list to a set, iterating over it and calling a count (presumably O(N) for each item in the set.

Comment: You're right it is more than likely O(n^2), although I think its fun in that python sort of way

Comment: a generator expression instead of the list comprehension is sufficient. also, using a tuple instead of the inner list looks nicer, i think.

Answer (score 7):

I dunno, it basically looks fine to me.  Your code is simple and easy to read which is an important part of what I consider pythonic.

You could trim it up a bit like so:

```
for k in a_list:
     kvMap[k] = 1 + kvMap.get(k,0)
```

Comment: that's what I Was gonna post!

Answer (score 6):

Such an old question, but considering that adding to a `defaultdict(int)` is such a common use, It should come as no surprise that `collections` has a special name for that (since Python 2.7)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4])
Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1})
>>> Counter("banana")
Counter({'a': 3, 'n': 2, 'b': 1})
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution exploits setdefault():

```
for k in a_list:
    kvMap[k] = kvMap.setdefault(k, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list is sorted, an alternative way would be to use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby). This might not be the most effective way, but it's interesting nonetheless. It retuns a dict of item > count :

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7]
>>> dict([(key, len([e for e in group]))
          for (key, group)
          in itertools.groupby(l)])
{1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 3, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 1}
```

Comment: the outer list comprehension is not necessary; a generator expression is enough.

Comment: dict((key, len(list(group)))
          for (key, group)
          in itertools.groupby(l))