# Python: Find index of the first occurrence of x and then the index of the second occurrence of x

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a list and find the index of the first occurrence of x and the index of the second occurrence of x.

I have the following list:

```
int_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 14, 15, 15, 17, 17, 14, 20, 20, 5, 23, 23, 25, 26, 26, 28, 28, 25, 31, 32, 32, 31, 35, 35, 4, 3, 39, 39, 41, 42, 42, 44, 44, 41, 47, 47, 2, 50, 50, 1, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 58, 60, 60, 62, 62, 57, 65, 66, 67, 67, 66, 65, 56, 72, 73, 74, 75, 75, 74, 78, 78, 73, 72, 82, 83, 83, 85, 85, 82, 55, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 93, 92, 91, 90, 98, 99, 99, 98, 102, 103, 103, 102, 106, 106, 89, 109, 109, 54, 112, 113, 113, 112, 116, 116, 53, 119, 120, 121, 121, 120, 119, 0, 126, 127, 128, 128, 130, 131, 131, 130, 127, 135, 135, 126]
```

I would like to start from index 0 which is a 1, as this is the first occurrence assign this to first_index, then search the rest of the list until I find another 1 which is at index 1 and so on.

I understand I need to use enumerate() which will loop through my list and allow me to find the index, however I am struggling with how to find the first and second occurrences

for example:

```
for i, e in enumerate(int_list):
    # if e 'is the first occurrence':
         first_index = i
    # else e is second occurrence:
         second_index = i
```

I don't know how to determine whether e is the first or second occurrence

I have tried the following code:

```
for i in int_list:

    first_ind = firstInt_ls.index(i, 0)
    second_ind = firstInt_ls.index(i, first_ind+1)

    print(first_ind)
    print(second_ind)
```

Which works unless there is only one occurrence. If there is not a second occurrence it produces a ValueError: 10 is not in list

Comment: you can use `enumerate()`. There is a lot posted about it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's the pythonic way to count the occurrence of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429414/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-count-the-occurrence-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Comment: Yeah sorry @Prune, I was half way through writing and I somehow accidentally posted it before I was ready, I am in the process of completing it now

Comment: If you want all occurances use `enumerate()` if you just want the 2nd one, use list.index like `int_list.index(1, int_list.index(1)+1)`

Comment: I only want the first and second occurrence. I have looked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429414/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-count-the-occurrence-of-an-element-in-a-list however I can't see how this solves my problem

Comment: `enumerate` is the way. Search this function to see how it works.

Comment: You could use enumerate, but you don't need to. Use list's index method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list's index() function, where the first argument is the element you are trying to find and the second argument is the index to start from. Maybe something like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 1, 5]

first_ind_of_one = a.index(1, 0)
second_ind_of_one = a.index(1, first_ind_of_one+1)

print(first_ind_of_one)
print(second_ind_of_one)
```

Code below for case when we don't know if and how many occurrences of element in list:

```
occurrences_needed = 2
list_of_inds = []
for ind, elem in enumerate(a):
    if len(list_of_inds) == occurrences_needed:
        break
    if elem == 1:
        list_of_inds.append(ind)

print(list_of_inds)
```

Just for fun, I have added a third method that is easier to read but may be inefficient for large lists (some testing may be required):

```
s = ''.join(str(i) for i in a)
first_ind = s.find('1')
second_ind = s.find('1', first_ind + 1)
print(first_ind)
print(second_ind)
```

This converts the list to a string and use's string's find() method. This method simply returns -1 in the event where the element is not found. So you may have to check for that in your code.

Comment: Thank you, this works well when there is more than one occurrence, however when there is only one occurrence it is giving an error i.e: ValueError: 10 is not in list

Comment: That is true, it also fails for 0 occurrences or if a list is empty. I have updated my answer to include a more robust example.